# How to create a table in SQLite Ionic?

Tags: javascript, sql, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a class and constructor inside of it:

```html
class DataBase {
  constructor(private sqlite: SQLite) {  //The begining of Constructor
      this.sqlite.create({
          name: 'data.db',
          location: 'default'
      })
      .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        debugger;
          db.executeSql('create table Newslist(name VARCHAR(32))', {})
            .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
            .catch(e => console.log(e));
      });
  } //The end of Constructor 
}
```

My code is OK. No mistakes. But when I go to the browser console, I see nothing in it.

My final goal is to see 'create table Newslist' .

I know that I need to create an object in the body of constructor to see something. AppComponent would be usefull as well.

But how to write it?

Comment: SQLite is a Cordova plugin. So it works only on the Mobile device. Check it on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is a Cordova/ionic's plugin. I will not work in the browser. Try to run on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Add the plugin cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-sqlite

After adding this plugin define globle variable in app.js like this "var db;"
then create database in SQLITE by below line

> db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name:"question.db", location:'default'});

once you created databse then you will able to create table by below line.

> $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_result (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,que_title TEXT ,right_option TEXT,wrong_option TEXT,result INTEGER)');

here 'question.db' is database name
     'user_result' is table name and
     'id,que_title..' are fields name of table.

For IONIC2/3 refere this link "https://ampersandacademy.com/tutorials/ionic-framework-version-2/sqlite-native-plugin-example"

Comment: link is not workable. Should I create an object 'db = $cordova ... ..." inside of my app.module.ts ? I've create a class DataBase and a constructor inside of it. Cannot find name cordovaSQLite. Cannot find 'execute' method.

Comment: yes,you can create  an object 'db = $cordova ... ..." inside of my app.module.ts.